# Which swift Document or video I need to read for me to understand how this ResultsHandler works?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

HI I'm a newbi coder who is code for fun.
I want to get my stepscount from my iPhone

so I start to learn Xcode and swift.

I can write bash script and a little bit python.

but I really can't understand the following.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery

```
    query.initialResultsHandler = {
    query, results, error in
```

// My Understanding This Handler is a unknow type or thing for me how can I know what is it and how to use it from apple's web page? 
I can tell from reading apple's page it have three components and
Declaration says it's a var? like

```
    var initialResultsHandler: ((HKStatisticsCollectionQuery, HKStatisticsCollection?, Error?) -> Void)? { get set }
```

so it's a var with three things in it? so it's a tuple? and can be get and set!?

So I think the above code means put var query to hander's HKStatisticsCollectionQuery, get from hander's HKStatisticsCollectionQuery to var results and handle's Error to local var error

The Most important thing is what is the "in" after the error?
I only know you can for xxxx in yyyy and create a loop but without a for use in means what? what document explain this in stuff?

```
    guard let statsCollection = results else {
        // Perform proper error handling here
        fatalError("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error?.localizedDescription) ***")
    }

    let endDate = NSDate()

    guard let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -3, toDate: endDate, options: []) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to calculate the start date ***")
    }
```

Comment: [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html) is a good start. The [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) chapter would be relevant to understanding the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a closure you are looking at. The three variables are the input arguments of the closure that you name `query`, `results` and `error`. You could give these any other name as well, since they only exist inside the closure and only their types are used in the function type signature.

The `in` keyword indicates the start of the closure body.

For more information on the topic, have a look at the [Closures chapter of the Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).